# ¿Cuál es la línea entre una pregunta basada en opiniones y una pregunta teórica?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

He estado en SOes por medio año y a lo largo de este tiempo he visto que generalmente las preguntas teóricas son mal recibidas y muchas de ellas son cerradas por estar basadas en opiniones.

Me gustaría poner de ejemplo [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/485506/cu%C3%A1ndo-debo-usar-herencia-interface-o-una-clase-abstracta/485516#485516) **(no quiero discutir sobre esto, sólo es un ejemplo)** que yo consideré bien hecha en un inicio<sup>[A]</sup>, pues consideré que cumplía con lo básico: investigación previa, buena ortografía, etiquetas bien colocadas y era directa. Por lo que al encontrármela en la sección de revisión de preguntas, me pareció inadecuado y decidí a contestarla.

La pregunta al inicio fue recibida bien con `+6 y -1`, posteriormente fue cerrada y cambió a `+6 -2`. Para ello tuvieron que haber varios votos de cierre, por lo que creo que hay un vacío gigantesco en nuestra definición de qué es una pregunta teórica y qué es una pregunta basada en opiniones. **LA TEORÍA NO ES UNA OPINIÓN**

A lo que voy es que me gustaría proponer que entre todos creemos un nuevo artículo donde se describan las características que debiese cumplir una pregunta teórica y qué la diferencia de preguntar por opiniones, para poder argumentar si realmente debe cerrarse y también serviría para que aquellas personas con esa curiosidad por la teoría tengan una guía, pues creo que a veces es más difícil preguntar por teoría (saber delimitar el tema y hacer las preguntas correctas) que poner una pregunta sobre código.

Como comentario adicional quisiera mencionar que he visto mayor aceptación de preguntas teóricas en SO (y similares a otras preguntas cerradas aquí), ¿Por qué no en SOes?

> If you find that you're spending almost all your time on theory, start turning some attention to practical things; it will improve your theories. If you find that you're spending almost all your time on practice, start turning some attention to theoretical things; it will improve your practice. — Donald Knuth
>
> ---
>
> Si descubres que estás dedicando casi todo tu tiempo a la teoría, comienza a prestar atención a las cosas prácticas; mejorará tus teorías. Si descubres que estás dedicando casi todo tu tiempo a la práctica, comienza a prestar atención a las cosas teóricas; mejorará tu práctica. — Donald Knuth

## EDIT:

Comunidad linda y querida, como había especificado **no me interesa discutir sobre la pregunta que puse como ejemplo**, la puse como ejemplo para que se viera que no tenemos bien definido qué es y qué no es una pregunta teórica. Y justo pasó lo mismo que aquella ocasión

A partir de esta publicación:

- hubo 2 votos positivos más a la pregunta
- hubo comentarios y personas que no están de acuerdo de que sea una buena pregunta

Por lo que puedo reforzar la conclusión de que **no hay un camino claro de situaciones como esta o similares.**

<sub>A: Al inicio consideré bien hecha luego me di cuenta que puede ser cerrada por ser demasiado amplia pero no cerrada por estar basada en opiniones.</sub>

Comment: La duda del OP en la pregunta que enlazas es: *¿Cuándo debo utilizar una Herencia, Interface y una Clase Abstracta?*, lo cuál es realmente opinable. Incluso un [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/485506/cu%C3%A1ndo-debo-usar-herencia-interface-o-una-clase-abstracta/485516#comment863653_485506) en dicha pregunta lo enfatiza. Y es que la pregunta planteada no es de teoría, tal como argumentas aquí, es de opinión, y es que no existe un consenso científico sobre cuándo se debe usar una estructura u otra, todo va a depender del proyecto y las necesidades. Saludos

Comment: Hay preguntas teóricas con respuestas precisas, no sujetas a opiniones. Por ejemplo, preguntas sobre automatas finitos o máquinas de Turing tienen respuestas matemáticamente demostrables.

Comment: Python tiene herencia, pero no interfaces, optando por un mecanismo alternativo (*duck typing*). Por tanto, un programador Java y otro Python tendrían respuestas distintas a esa pregunta, ambas igualmente válidas en sus respectivos eco-sistemas. Por tanto, es una pregunta basada en opiniones.

Comment: no existe una linea que separe lo que pregunta, hay una sona gris no definida que es evaluada por la comunidad, son ellos los que emiten votos +, - y de cierre, para este tipo de preguntas. para emitir estos votos en teoria como dices deben basarce en las normas del sitio, y en su sentido comun ya que hay preguntas que pueden caer en multiples motivos de cierre a la vez.

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent Es a lo que me refiero exactamente, ¿Cómo podemos ayudar a que esa "zona gris" se más pequeña? ¿Podemos ayudar a las personas que se encuentran en estos casos con un artículo que ayude a la comunidad a decidir?

Comment: si hay una forma: cerrando la pregunta y esperar a que el usuario incluya mas detalles sobre el contexto, o queel determine si hay un problema cual es para apoyarlo con el problema cualquier otro escenario se escapa de los topicos del sitio..

Comment: El OP pregunta que usar?, es importante agregar lo que investigo, si es posible definir el lenguaje, si tiene dudas a partir de una investigación la respuesta se podría acotar, algunas cosas de tu respuesta no me parecen correctas. Lo primero es ayudar a el OP a formular su pregunta de acuerdo a [ask] para que entienda el funcionamiento del sitio de otra forma continuará con el mismo patrón al formular las preguntas, aquí otra pregunta con características similares del mismo usuario https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465301/usar-variables-privadas-en-otra-clase-no-principal

Comment: no existen preguntas teoricas... las preguntas teoricas son el equivalente a que es en la teoria mas rapido: un for o while o foreach??? el siguiente nivel es sobre dependencias de los escenarios pero basado en sujerencias... si no existe una respuesta de la fuente oficial toda respuesta queda expuesta a una interpretacion personal y esto es conciderado una sujerencia de como hacer las cosas o que implementar.

Comment: sin enbargo existe respuestas canonicas en php puedes preguntar si estas haciendo uso correcto de PSR-12 en un codigo de ejemplo. es aceptable incluso para refactorizar. la respuesta es canonica por que la fuente oficial ha establecido las reglas para ese codigo y cualquier respuesta es una correccion, no una sujerencia.

Comment: las preguntas sobre refactorizacion de codigo rayan en las sujerencias, deben estar muy bien planteadas y deben haber considerado la investigacion... estas son mejor recibidas en code review(uso especifico) las que se ven en SOes (deben ser de uso general para la comunidad) .

Answer (score 1):

Todo lenguaje que ofrezca distintas funcionalidades, para llegar a un mismo punto, puede basar su implementación en opiniones tomando en cuenta los pro y los contras de cada funcionalidad, la teoría es la documentacion que te explica los caminos/vía y cuales de ellas o como son mejores para cada caso dado, pero no te obliga, solo plantear correctamente el contexto y escenario te llevara a la mejor respuesta y no únicamente la teoría. ya que los lenguajes de programación tienen la virtud de ser mejorables.

Concuerdo en que las preguntas que solicitan sugerencias basadas en **Teorías en Particular/especificas** sean aceptadas si se incluye el escenario, de los contrario sean cerradas por ser muy amplias.

Concuerdo en que las preguntas que solicitan sugerencias basadas en **Teorías ambiguas/numerosas e indeterminadas** sean cerradas basadas en opiniones.

por ejemplo esta publicación de un compañero, esta basada en una herramienta y un escenario especifico, demostró haber investigado, y aunque existe numerosas formas de realizar el procedimiento... la respuesta oficial teórica solo era una.

[¿Una vez que hice un PR de un repo, debo borrar mi fork?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/155381/una-vez-que-hice-un-pr-de-un-repo-debo-borrar-mi-fork)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu pregunta es muy interesante, pero no elegiste un buen ejemplo. Ya leí que no quieres discutir sobre el ejemplo que diste, pero debo decirte, que a mi criterio, no sirve como pregunta de opinión, creo que en todo caso debió haber sido cerrada por ser demasiado amplia, además del titulo, en el cuerpo tenemos otras tres preguntas, responderla es un capítulo de un libro de OOP, entiendo que con un buen marco teórico se podría dar una respuesta que no se considere opinión, pero sería demasiado extensa para el formato del sitio.

Pero, volviendo al tema de tu inquietud, la visión de SO no es la de ser un foro, por eso se trata de evitar por todos los medios que las preguntas generen la dinámica de los foros. Aquí las preguntas tienen que ser concretas y tienen que tener una o más respuestas también concretas. Una opinión, puede ser útil pero nunca podrá ser una respuesta concreta: para algunos tal vez funcione para otros tal vez no.

Con respecto a:

> ¿Cuál es la línea entre una pregunta basada en opiniones y una
> pregunta teórica?

A mi criterio la misma línea que separa una opinión de cualquier otra clase de pregunta. Una pregunta teórica puede ser válida si la respuesta que se pueda dar sea concreta y no una opinión.

Como siempre es un tema de criterio de los que votamos y de cierto consenso que se construye con el tiempo en la comunidad. En mi caso observar ciertas cosas cuando evaluó una pregunta pueden hacer inclinar la balanza:

- ¿Se está pidiendo una respuesta concreta o simplemente se quiere leer lo que piensa la comunidad?
- ¿La pregunta puede recibir eventualmente respuestas antagónicas y que aún así sean válidas?
- Hay también ciertas formas de construir una pregunta que "encienden la alarma": ¿Qué me recomiendan? ¿Qué es mejor? ¿Qué me conviene?

Comment: ***si la respuesta que se pueda dar sea concreta y no una opinión*** creo que hay que aclarar que esto se puede sustentar cuando la fuente es oficial: por ejemplo cuando la pregunta se basa en bootstrap y la respuesta se extrajo del sitio de oficial o del github.

Comment: con eso se logra el ***No es mi opinión, así lo decidió el creador etc...***